# How do I increase the throw distance of a character?

Tags: disgaea-5

I don't see any items in particular that increase throw distance. Is there a way to change it on a particular character during or outside of battle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to increase a character's throw range is through the "Chara World", which unlocks at the beginning of chapter 6. A throwing range increase is one of the selectable rewards for reaching the goal of a Chara World map.